# En el Admin añadir el selector de permisos del usuario a otro field ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

tengo un modelo con un Field ManyToMany, pero en panel de administradora perecer de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que se vea como los gruops o los permisos que también son fields ManyToMany, que es de la siguiente manera, ¿es posible hacerlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar el estilo de los Groups y Permisos en un field ManyToMany añadiendo en el amdin.py la propiedad filter_horizontal, dejo un ejemplo más abajo de uso.

**admin.py**

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['nameField']
```